# Dynamic Select drop downs stop working when I add one line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script.  It loads data in dynamic select drop downs on my webpage.  All works fine until I add line 27 where I noted `//when this line is inserted code stops working.`  The next drop down for sub_category will not load data when this line 27 is added. With this line of code I am trying to grab the next name value in the array. If I alert product_type_next I can see the value, but my sub_category drop down will not load with data when this line is added.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#category_item').selectpicker();
  $('#sub_category_item').selectpicker();
  $('#model_year_item').selectpicker();
  $('#model_item').selectpicker();

  load_data('category_data');

  function load_data(type, category_id = '', category_id1 = '', category_id2 = '')
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"load_data.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{type:type, category_id:category_id, category_id1:category_id1, category_id2:category_id2},
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data)
      {
        var html = '';
        for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
        {
      if (type == 'sub_category_data') {

              var product_type=(data[count].name);
              var product_type_next=(data[count+1].name); //when this line is inserted code stops working

        switch (true) {
            case (count == 0):
                html += '<optgroup label="'+data[count].name+'">';
                html += '<option value="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].sub+'</option>';
                break;

            case (count !== 0):
                html += '<option value="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].sub+'</option>';
                break;
        }

      } 
      else {
              html += '<option style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f0ec;" value="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].name+'</option>';
          }
        }
        if(type == 'category_data')
        {
          $('#category_item').html(html);
          $('#category_item').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
        else if (type == 'sub_category_data')
        {
          $('#sub_category_item').html(html);
          $('#sub_category_item').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
        else if (type == 'model_year_data')
        {
          $('#model_year_item').html(html);
          $('#model_year_item').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
        else if (type == 'model_data')
        {
          $('#model_item').html(html);
          $('#model_item').selectpicker('refresh');
        }

      }
    })
  }

  $(document).on('change', '#category_item', function(){
    var category_id = $('#category_item option:selected').text();
    load_data('sub_category_data', category_id);
  }); 

  $(document).on('change', '#sub_category_item', function(){
    //var category_id = $('#category_item').text();
    var category_id = $('#sub_category_item option:selected').text();
    var category_id1 = $('#category_item option:selected').text();
    load_data('model_year_data', category_id, category_id1);
  }); 

  $(document).on('change', '#model_year_item', function(){
    var category_id = $('#model_year_item option:selected').text();
    var category_id1 = $('#category_item option:selected').text();
    var category_id2 = $('#sub_category_item option:selected').text();
    load_data('model_data', category_id, category_id1, category_id2);
  }); 


});

</script>
```

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to access past the end of the array (`data[count+1].name`) on the last entry and that's causing a javascript error.  Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: @mrrogers makes perfect sense now.  I spent so much time trying to figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: @kinglish thank you as well.  I tried this and it creates an error as well.  Is there another method I can use?  I tried exactly like you have and like this:  `var product_type_next=(data[count+1]?.name : "");`

Comment: You can use this to suppress the error and return an empty string when you are checking for the next item at the end of the array (where there isn't a next item) `var product_type_next=data[count+1]?.name || ""; `

Comment: @user1609391 - I had a typo, try new comment

Comment: @Kinglish  You're awesome, that worked.  Thank you so much!